# Importing products from one site to another in Magento

Tags: magento

Im currently hosting my Magento website and i want to make another website without adding any new products in in newsite. I want to importy products from the older website to newer one.

I tried dumping the older database to the newer one but does'nt help. 
Is there any other possible way ??

Answer (score 0):

You could re-create the attribute sets and categories on the old site and export the products using

```
System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles
```

However that does not solve the issue of grouped or configurable products, or product options if you have them. If that is the case, you might need to upgrade your existing installation (or ensure it is the same version as the new website) and then copy the database across.

Comment: agreed for the import/export, but try to avoid old Dataflow profiles as it's pretty slow (New Import/Export functionnality is much better)

Comment: I tried to import database but it provides my constraint error.